# Render showing bright and dark parts

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Just like the picture below, there's this border that shows a bright and dark part of the render. This don't show up on viewport. I don't really know how this is happening.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u0Bn.jpg)

Comment: Need more info. Whats viewport look like? Do you have hidden objects? Whats blender version, render settings?

Comment: No hidden objects, just a volumetric scatter object. Blender 3.0, 128 samples, denoiser on, and basically default settings.

Comment: Upload the blender file somewhere because there are still so many reasons this could be happening.

Comment: Do you have auto tile size addon enabled ? if yes, disable it

Comment: I don't have auto tile. Here's the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JYXV2jUvgDFDzoyy9qH00i-i6ymstluU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i couldn't reproduce your result -> this is my 2 sec render: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvk6z.jpg and here 20sec render: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbJ6r.jpg

Comment: maybe update Blender version?

Comment: Thanks, updating to 3.1 helps.

Comment: @max1eee - [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) should be used for Blender Stack Exchange.